# How to use BeautifulSoup to find multiple div with the same td tag

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, tags

I want to extract the contents of the highlighted td div.(The actual code is more complex)
I'm trying to use BeautifulSoup's Find_all() search for elements that have the tag "div" and the same "td" tag.
But my attempt has failed.  How can i correct my code?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nwoNS.png

Comment: Share your current code. Remember to format the code with { } or ctrl-k

Answer (score 0):

By using the CSS selector

`div.my_tbl_wrap > p > table > tbody > tr > td:nth-child-of(2) > p`

and `soup.findAll(__selector__)` you can loop through each element that satisfies your condition. I suggest using chrome to to extract the css selector. The above selector may not work. The quality of my answer reflects the quality of your question.